# AWS botocore exception

Tags: aws-cli

I had a CLI account set up previously with AWS Amplify. I deleted the credentials in the .aws folder and added a new key from an iam user account. When I finish the "aws configure" command all seems well, however when I run "aws list iam-users" to check for success. I receive the message

"Unable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received. Further retries may succeed:
b'' "

I'm getting the following debug log. I'm very new to AWS and find the whole thing a bit daunting. Any one got any suspicions on what could be tripping up the cli parser?

```
2022-08-28 14:50:48,942 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Exception caught in main()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "awscli\botocore\parsers.py", line 490, in _parse_xml_string_to_dom
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "awscli\clidriver.py", line 458, in main
  File "awscli\clidriver.py", line 593, in __call__
  File "awscli\clidriver.py", line 769, in __call__
  File "awscli\clidriver.py", line 902, in invoke
  File "awscli\clidriver.py", line 924, in _display_response
  File "awscli\formatter.py", line 82, in __call__
  File "awscli\botocore\paginate.py", line 446, in build_full_result
  File "awscli\botocore\paginate.py", line 252, in __iter__
  File "awscli\botocore\paginate.py", line 329, in _make_request
  File "awscli\botocore\client.py", line 304, in _api_call
  File "awscli\botocore\client.py", line 620, in _make_api_call
  File "awscli\botocore\client.py", line 640, in _make_request
  File "awscli\botocore\endpoint.py", line 101, in make_request
  File "awscli\botocore\endpoint.py", line 133, in _send_request
  File "awscli\botocore\endpoint.py", line 165, in _get_response
  File "awscli\botocore\endpoint.py", line 219, in _do_get_response
  File "awscli\botocore\parsers.py", line 246, in parse
  File "awscli\botocore\parsers.py", line 543, in _do_error_parse
  File "awscli\botocore\parsers.py", line 492, in _parse_xml_string_to_dom
botocore.parsers.ResponseParserError: Unable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received. Further retries may succeed:
b''
```

Comment: Delete everything in .../.aws and then run `aws configure` again

Comment: This did it, after rebooting the terminal, it worked. Thanks! :P

Comment: So aws configure is creating no files? Are you sure it's not just hidden in your view? Retry the commands

Comment: It did actually, I just needed to refresh file explorer! Really grateful, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Ermiya who suggested the fix.

I had edited the keys of the credentials manually which caused a parsing error. After deleting the .aws folder completely I reran `aws configure` and aws rebuilt the folder and the following command

`aws iam list-users` worked correctly